# How to put tabs containing ListFragment on the left and a details panel on the right?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to show two tabs each containing ListFragment classes. On clicking any item of the list, it's details should open on the right panel on landscape views. This is much like the official Android fragments example.
 [image]
What I want to achieve is that on the left side of the layout the list view should be in tabs, i.e. two list views within tabs. On clicking any item the details should open on the right. Till now, I can show tabs and details, but the details are not showing up on the right. They open as a new activity. 
Tab Navigation can be an option, but due to some design restraints in my app, I can't use that. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution. I am explaining how I did it, in case someone needs it.

I wanted to make tabs on the left fragment. Due to design constraints, I could not use Tab Navigation, as I had to use List Navigation too. 
So, I made a new fragment placed over the left fragment and inflated it with two buttons. On different button clicks, I used FragmentTransaction to add new fragment to the left fragment.

On button click listener I used fragmentTransaction.replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this android blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html It has a complete tutorial of how to use fragments as a Master-Details View.